# What are ng2 Forms useful for besides validation?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder, angular2-ngmodel

We have decided to do validation only on the backend in an Angular2 app. In this scenario, it seems like ng2's Forms, formBuilder, ngControls, etc. with their extra code are not necessary and add a lot of code. What are they useful for besides validation?

(P.S. Please don't respond with reasons that this is a bad idea. We know the context of our app and are aware of the pros and cons of server-side only validation. I'm wondering, would we regret not using ng2's Forms in this scenario? Do they have other useful or crucial functionality?)

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 forms update CSS classes that make them easy to style

```
+-----------------------------+---------------+----------------+  
|            State            | Class if true | Class if false |  
+-----------------------------+---------------+----------------+  
| Control has been visited    | ng-touched    | ng-untouched   |  
| Control's value has changed | ng-dirty      | ng-pristine    |  
| Control's value is valid    | ng-valid      | ng-invalid     |  
+-----------------------------+---------------+----------------+
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

The forms module also allows to build your forms the Angular2 way, where the DOM isn't accessed directly by your code.
You should only update the model and Angular2 updates the DOM accoringly.
This way the application can run on all supported platforms like server-side-rendering or web workers.